# Laptop wont wake when suspended on intel graphics (works fine on the same machine running nvidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, intel

Whenever I close my lid the screen turns off but the computer is still clearly on. Opening the lid does not wake it and the only way i have found to turn on the display again was to unplug and re-plug my power cable. My laptop has a dedicated graphics card as well (Nvidia GTX 1050ti) and while using it everything works fine. However I wish to use the integrated card when I don't need the more powerful one. Any ideas what the problem could be? I've checked other forums for answers but none seem to apply to me or don't work. I must add I am a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

In short: the laptop won't properly suspend when running integrated graphics but works fine on a different card.